# Python Get date from weekday of current week?

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to get date from weekday of current week

```
week_day = date.today().weekday()
```

From this `week_day` I'm trying to get exact day of week - `27/05/2021`

Comment: What's wrong with `date.today()`? Why do you need to use the weekday? How do you know what week it is (other than by using `date.today()`?)

What problem are you solving that requires such a roundabout approach?

Comment: @N.Wouda i have week_day number/name - Ex: Tuesday/1 , Friday/4. I need to get those current week dates based on week-day number or week-day name

Comment: @user15590480 [the `strptime` format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for weekday numbers assigns 0 to Sunday, 1 to Monday, ..., and finally 6 to Saturday. Your example seems to assign 0 to Monday, 1 to Tuesday, ... So it's off by one with respect to the standard. Is that due to just the example, or something you have in actual data?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to fetch a `date` of the current week's weekday by number (or name, but you can easily make the transition).

I can propose you the following function, computing the difference with the current date:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
def date_for_weekday(day: int):
     today = date.today()
     # weekday returns the offsets 0-6
     # If you need 1-7, use isoweekday
     weekday = today.weekday()
     return today + timedelta(days=day - weekday)

# Usage
>>> date_for_weekday(0)
datetime.date(2021, 5, 24)
>>> date_for_weekday(1)
datetime.date(2021, 5, 25)
>>> date_for_weekday(4)
datetime.date(2021, 5, 28)
>>> date_for_weekday(3)
datetime.date(2021, 5, 27)
```